# Compare two NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray containing NSMutableDictionary values. I have to identify a particular dictionary value exist in that NSMutableArray or not?

NSMutableArray:

tableData:

```
{
    {

        categories = 267;
        "category_ids" = 267;
        "created_at" = "2012-04-18 05:32:10";
        "custom_design_from" = "2010-12-03 00:00:00";
    }
    {
        categories = 267;
        "category_ids" = 267;
        "created_at" = "2012-04-18 05:32:10";
        "custom_design_from" = "2010-12-03 00:00:00";
    }
 }
```

I have to identify the one particular dictionary value.

My Code:

```
if ( [tableData containsObject:[appDelegate.Product objectAtIndex:i]] ) 
{
     // Return Always false...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, `containsObject:` method check if array contains given object by sending `isEqual:` message to all instances in it. NSDictionary class has method isEqualToDictionary: that comares dictionary's content. You can try to make smth like this

```
- (BOOL) dictionaryArray:(NSMutableArray*)array containsDictionary:(NSDictionary*)givenDictionary
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    for( NSDictionary* dict in array )
    {
        if( [dict isEqualToDictionary:givenDictionary] )
        {
            result = YES;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

this method should return if your array contains given dictionary by calling

```
NSDictionary* dict = [appDelegate.Product objectAtIndex:i];
if ( [self dictionaryArray:tableData containsDictionary:dict] )
{
    // do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That could happen if the 2 dictionaries contain the same data but they are not the same object
For example (`NSDictionary`)

```
NSDictionary *d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"1"];
NSDictionary *d2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"1"];
if(d1 == d2)
   //Does note get called
```

s1 has same data of s2
but the objects are different
so a normal equality test will never work

Thats maybe what is happening to you
You may have 2 dictionaries with the same data structure but they are not really the same object

You will have to elaborate more on your dictionaries, by testing the actual strings or ids in the NSDictionary

Comment: An internal machanism in iOS enshures, that two NSString-Objects are identic if their contents are identic. So in your example s1 and s2 are two names of the same object. But this is only true for objects of type NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Two Objects that contain identic data are normally not identic. An Example:

```
NSMutableArray* array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", nil];
NSMutableArray* array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"x", @"y", nil];
NSMutableArray* array3 = array2;
```

Now, of course, array1 is a different object than array2 while array2 and array3 are the same objekt.

```
1: a
2: x, y
3: x, y
```

So, lets change one of them:

```
[array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"x"];
[array1 addObject:@"y"];
```

Now all three arrays have identical content, but still array1 and array 2 are different objects:

```
1: x, y
2: x, y
3: x, y
```

Lets do another change:

```
[array2 addObject:@"z"];
```

Since array1 is a different object then array2, changing of array 2 did not affect array1.
But array2 is identic to array3 (array2 and array3 are just two names for the same thing):

```
1: x, y
2: x, y, z
3: x, y, z
```